# List Email Settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have already configured the settings for this, but it seems that I have to go to each individual list that's created and enable "send email when ownership is assigned" in the list settings.

Is there a way to enable the setting for all lists on the site simultaneously rather than having to do it on an individual list basis?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a powershell script on the server, but it's likely that it would be faster to do it manually unless you have hundreds of these lists.